# Facebook Connect - how to display in a popup?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

If you do this,

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
  scope=email,user_birthday&
  client_id=123050457758183&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response&
  response_type=token&
  display=popup
```

It works but it redirects to facebook URL, however if I load it in a popup, then facebook does not display the page at all. (instead it displays facebook logo see image below

[image]

Why does this happen??? how do you display facebook login in a popup window anyways?
(because its not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I navigate to that page. How do you open the popup? Perhaps it gets blocked by a popup blocker..

May I recommend you to look into using FBJS to open the popup? Something like this:

```
FB.login(function() {
 // handle the response
}, { perms: 'email,user_birthday' });
```

Comment: Hmm, so you are using the javascript sdk? I followed this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/